# Icalendar dates problem - my date is out by 2 days

Tags: icalendar

I have a calendar file which I will post below. The problem is that when I load this into outlook the date says the 24/02/2011. The date in the file as shown below is the 22/02/2011
(START:201102**22**T100000).

I am in Sydney/Australia if that makes any difference.

Can anyone try adding this to their outlook calendars and see if the date is wrong?

Here is a link to the file: http://www.onlinerego.com/small_business_summit2011/assets/template/ics/sydney.ics

Thanks so much.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//http://testing.cdw/thegoldbook///NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.8//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20110208T111839EST-4800GDFvWN@http://testing.cdw/thegoldbook/
DTSTAMP:20110208T000239Z
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en:Thank you for registering to attend the 'Trend Micr
 o Affinity Partner Small Business Summit 2011'.\n\nWe look forward to seei
 ng you at the event!\n\nDate: 22 February\nVenue: Novotel Darling Harbour\
 , Terrace Room\nAddress: 100 Murray St\, Darling Harbour\nArrival time: 10
 :00am\n\nAgenda\n10.00am - Pre registration & Networking\n10.30am - Exploi
 ting Small Business Trends to increase your profits\, By Toby Lee\, Global
  Vice President\, Volume Business Unit\, Trend Micro\n11.00am - Product Ro
 admap for Small Business\, By Richard Ku\, Global Vice President\, Small B
 usiness Product Management\, Trend Micro\n11.15am - Break\n11.45am - Affin
 ity Program and Channel Engagement Update\, By Malcolm Pooley\, ANZ Small 
 Business Channel Sales Manager\n12.00pm - Q&A Panel\n12.15pm - Close\n\nUR
 L - http://www.onlinerego.com/small_business_summit2011/thankyou.php?city=
 Sydney
DTSTART:20110222T100000
DTEND:20110222T121500
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en:Novotel Darling Harbour\, Terrace Room\, 100 Murray St
 \, Darling Harbour
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en:Trend Micro Affinity Partner Small Business Summit 2011
URL:http://www.onlinerego.com/small_business_summit2011/thankyou.php?city=S
 ydney
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also in Aus.

Loading into my google (sydney time) gives Tue, 22 February, 21:00 – 23:15 - so wrong times but right date.   Google may assume it is UTC time and are we currently +11, that may explain it's time.  No idea what outlook is doing.

windows calendar has 22 feb and 10 am

my own app also gives 22 Feb and 10 am

The way dates are specified and whether you have a timezone or not makes a difference.

The file does not have a timezone spec and the dates are specified in "local" format - ie: should translate to 10 am in whatever timezone you load it into ... dangerous as if it were a conference call meeting across timezones for eg, it should have a timezone associated with it.

Either in the DTSTART

**DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20101031T190000**

or using the X-WR-TIMEZONE custom field

**X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York**

Sorry no idea what outlook is doing though (I do not use it).

Comment: That advice was good. I used a TZID:Australia/Sydney and a X-WR-TIMEZONE:Australia/Sydney in the top part of the file worked like a charm. thanks